# How to horizontally center a larger div of variable width, within a smaller div of variable width

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following effect: http://jsfiddle.net/3KJta/1/

[image]

However the solution I have uses a **known** width for the small div and the larger div.  I need this to work with **variable** sized divs.  The use case for this is a tooltip that appears above a smaller flexible sized element.  The tooltip content isn't known and so the width could be anything.

So far I have:

```
<div class="small">
    <div class="smaller"></div>
    <div class="larger"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.small {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.smaller {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.larger {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -75px /* NOTE: in reality, .small has a variable width, and so does .larger, so i can't just take off this fixed margin */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with using css3 and only support modern browsers you can use `transform: translateX(-50%);` to center the bigger box ([currently supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)).

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2SQ4S/1/

Comment: oh, that's clever :) luckily I only support IE9+ so this is just what I need - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use and extra element you can do it:

```
<div class="small">
    <div class="smaller"></div>
    <div class="larger">
        <div>I'm extra</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.larger {
    position:relative; 
    left:50%;
    width:8000%;
    margin-left:-4000%;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
}
.larger div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-color: blue;
    margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KJta/4/

although that does cause some issues with content being wider than the page so you would need it all in a container with `overflow:hidden`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3KJta/7/

All a bit ugly though. Perhaps there's a solution where you can avoid doing this. Maybe a JS solution that measures the size of the content you're trying to show and offsets it.